# Disabling button when textfield is empty wait for any change in other textfield

Tags: swift, uitextfield, textfield, disable

I wanna disable log in button if email or password textfield is empty and enable it again when both are filled so i use the below code:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if txtEmail.text != "" , txtPassword.text != "" {
        btnLogInOutlet.isEnabled = true
    }else if txtEmail.text! == "" || txtPassword.text! == "" {
        btnLogInOutlet.isEnabled = false
    }
    return true
}
```

The problem appears when i type in both fields then i delete what i type in one of those fields . As you can see in the picture below , the button still enabled.It only become disabled again if i start editing in the other (not empty) textfield.

[image]

My question is How to disable the button again directly after i delete what i type in any textfield before i move to another one??

Comment: This is all happening because you are not considering "string" value in the function. To get new string you need to add/remove it from the textfield.text. This should help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the text value from your textfield before returning true from your delegate - it means that it has old value, before the change.

Instead of using `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method, use the action (you can also hook it up using storyboards):

```
txtEmail.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
txtPassword.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Now in `textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField)` method you can copy paste your implementation (slightly improved here):

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
   btnLogInOutlet.isEnabled = !txtEmail.text.isEmpty && !txtPassword.text.isEmpty
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more details about action (addTarget) ?? where to add it and how to use it ??

Comment: You can set it up using Interface Builder or add it for example in your `viewDidLoad`. Here's more about target-action pattern: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html

Comment: I got it now , i did not know that textfield can have action too not only outlet .

Comment: @MichałKwiecień this is really creative way i will upvote :)

Answer (score 3):

try this ...initially disable your login button..

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loginbttn.isEnabled = false;
        textfield1.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)),  for:.editingChanged )
        textfield2.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)),  for:.editingChanged )

    }

 @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if textfield1.text == "" || textfield2.text == "" {
            loginbttn.isEnabled = false;
        }else{
             loginbttn.isEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: I think it will help too , i solve it using action on textfield ( when Editing change ) .

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


    if txtEmail.text != "" && txtPassword.text != "" {
        btnlogin.isEnabled = true
    }else if txtEmail.text! == "" || txtPassword.text! == "" {
        btnlogin.isEnabled = false

    }
    return true
}


func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if txtEmail.text != "" && txtPassword.text != "" {
        btnlogin.isEnabled = true
    }else if txtEmail.text! == "" || txtPassword.text! == "" {
        btnlogin.isEnabled = false

    }
    return true

}
```

you just have to put the same code in `textFieldShouldEndEditing` as well and it will work :)

Comment: It improves it a little it as it disable the button once i move to another textfield( before i even edit that textfield) . But my main problem still the same .  I want to disable the button once the user delete his text even before he moves to another texfield.

Comment: @MinaHanna TRY now i have updated my code as per ur requirement :)